# android supporting different resolution with layout folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I am creating layouts for an app but the problem is layout is perfect on all large devices but not suits on hdpi. So I think to create hdpi folder separate for layouts. I choose android resource directory and choose density as hdpi but not working for only hdpi devices. I tried dimensions and screen width also but not working. Can you please help me how can I improve it.

**Layout Code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/combine_bg"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp20"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp20"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp20">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtWelcomeTo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome_to"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp170"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dp15"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrivateCare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/the_private_care_masters"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtWelcomeTo" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etemail"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp190"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtPrivateCare"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
            android:hint="@string/email_phone"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp20" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp190"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/etemail"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
            android:hint="@string/password"

            />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/login_btn"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_below="@id/etemail"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp25"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/etemail" />


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkRememberMe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/etPassword"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
            android:text="@string/remember_me"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"

            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtForgotPwd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chkRememberMe"
            android:text="@string/forgot_pwd"
            android:layout_below="@id/etPassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp17"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp15"

            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSignUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/not_have_account"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtForgotPwd"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp30"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dp12"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp15"

            />


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And  screenhsot of .psd which I want to create

[image: screenhsot of .psd which I want to create]

And mine layout on hdpi device:

[image]

How can I resolve the problem please help

**dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="dp1">1dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dp2">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dp3">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dp4">4dp</dimen>
```

**dimens.xml-large**

```
<dimen name="dp1">1.5dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp2">3.0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp3">4.5dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp4">6.0dp</dimen>
```

**dimes.xml - xlarge**

```
 <dimen name="dp1">2.0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dp2">4.0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dp3">6.0dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Did you use `sp` or `ssp` for text size ??

Comment: Please post your `dimens.xml` file.

Comment: @AndréSousa check my edited code

Comment: @MohammadAli i used dp for text size

Comment: please use text size for `ssp` and any other things like margin, padding, use `sdp` for this two things you can find library @mishti

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `sp` instead of `dp` for your text sizes.

From the documentation:

> **sp**
>
> Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommended you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and user's preference.

Comment: it's right @Andre if don't know about `ssp` and `sdp` please refere : **[LINK](https://github.com/intuit/ssp)**. it's just kind for your information.

Comment: @MohammadAli Thanks! I will check it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please use SDP lib of [GitHub](https://github.com/intuit/sdp). By using this library you no need to handle all android device resolution automatically. You just create one only one UI file. 
This lib is very simple to use just past all dimension value folder in resource folder of your project or you can add its dependecy like below.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

You can also use SSP [GitHub](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) lib for your TextSize. Same like SDP lib

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
}
```